# How to get value from oracle Procedure to Simplejdbccall

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I have successfully saved the details using Simplejdbccall using spring and procedure but I need to return a value from procedure and get it in java code

1. i have used return statement in procedure but it doesn't  works

This is the java code

```
public void saveNamedDrivers(QuotationDO quotationDO) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

         System.out.println(" 11111");


        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
        simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName("NAMED_DRIVER_SAVE").withProcedureName("PR_NAMED_DRIVER_SAVE")
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_VCH_NAME", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("P_NUM_NEW_IC_NO", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("P_NUM_OLD_IC_NO", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("P_VCH_GENDER", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("P_VCH_RELATIONSHIP", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("P_NUM_AGE", OracleTypes.NUMBER),
                        new SqlParameter("P_VCH_DRIVER_EXPERIENCE", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));

        SqlParameterSource inputParams = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("P_VCH_NAME", quotationDO.getNameddrivername())
                .addValue("P_NUM_NEW_IC_NO", quotationDO.getNamednewicno())
                .addValue("P_NUM_OLD_IC_NO", quotationDO.getNamedoldicno())
                .addValue("P_VCH_GENDER", quotationDO.getNamedgender())
                .addValue("P_VCH_RELATIONSHIP", quotationDO.getNameddriverrelationship())
                .addValue("P_NUM_AGE", quotationDO.getNamedage())
                .addValue("P_VCH_DRIVER_EXPERIENCE", quotationDO.getNameddriverexperience());

        Map<String, Object> transactionStatus = simpleJdbcCall.execute(inputParams);
        System.out.println( transactionStatus);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

**How to change the procedure and java code to get value from procedure**

Sql Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SYSTEM.NAMED_DRIVER_SAVE AS PROCEDURE 
 PR_NAMED_DRIVER_SAVE (
      P_VCH_NAME VARCHAR2, 
      P_NUM_NEW_IC_NO VARCHAR2, 
      P_NUM_OLD_IC_NO VARCHAR2, 
      P_VCH_GENDER VARCHAR2, 
      P_VCH_RELATIONSHIP VARCHAR2, 
      P_NUM_AGE NUMBER, 
      P_VCH_DRIVER_EXPERIENCE VARCHAR2
 ) as 
      P_NAMED_ID NUMBER;
 BEGIN 
      BEGIN P_NAMED_ID := 0;
           SELECT SEQ_NAMED.NEXTVAL INTO P_NAMED_ID FROM DUAL;
      END;
 BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO EIS_TRN_NAMED_DRIVERS (
           NUM_S_NO, 
           VCH_NAME, 
           NUM_NEW_IC_NO, 
           NUM_OLD_IC_NO, 
           VCH_GENDER, 
           VCH_RELATIONSHIP, 
           NUM_AGE, 
           VCH_DRIVER_EXPERIENCE
           )VALUES(
           P_NAMED_ID, 
           P_VCH_NAME, 
           P_NUM_NEW_IC_NO, 
           P_NUM_OLD_IC_NO, 
           P_VCH_GENDER, 
           P_VCH_RELATIONSHIP, 
           P_NUM_AGE, 
           P_VCH_DRIVER_EXPERIENCE
           );
           COMMIT;
           EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
      end;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(P_NUM_AGE);
      RETURN;
      END PR_NAMED_DRIVER_SAVE;
 END NAMED_DRIVER_SAVE;
 /
```

[I got the output in debbuging sql procedure using `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(P_NAMED_ID);` but how to get it in above java code

1. Map String contains
2. procedure does not return anything it show warning

][Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijLvX.png)

Comment: RETURN doesn't do anything in a procedure. You need to specify an OUT parameter for whatever it is you want to return.

Comment: I have returned the P_NUM_AGE`return P_NUM_AGE;` i got this error
  [Error] PLS-00372 (59: 4): PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression

Comment: No, not a RETURN statement but [an OUT parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS209).

Comment: Yeah i have changed that to `P_NUM_AGE IN OUT NUMBER,` but
case 1 : i need to return `IN OUT PARAMETER `
case 2 : i need to return the sequence value

Comment: 1) There are two kinds of "subprograms" in PL/SQ:: "procedures" and "functions".  A "procedure" - by definition - *DOESN'T* "return* anything!.  That's what "functions" are for.  2) It sounds like the solution here is to use OUT, or an IN OUT, arguments.  Q: Did you try it?  Q: What happened?  Look here for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS246

Comment: For my case I need for both OUT and IN OUT parameters ..

I have tried using procedure by dbmsoutputline whether it is possible to reflect in Java code 

Or 

How to use function whether I need to change the whole Java and procedure structure to return a value ....